# "android" tag no longer blacklisted

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags

This was working for a time, but now new questions can get the [android](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/android) tag, whether asked here or migrated from another site. (Previously, migrated questions would get [untagged](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged) if "android" was the only tag on the question.)

Can this please be repaired? I am sure we're not the only site with tags that need blacklisting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hmm, indeed, somehow your blacklist was empty. That's very odd.

I reinstated the intrinsic tag of "android" just now.

Comment: Thank you, Jeff.